# Image is not acting like a link

Tags: html, css, django, wagtail

I have wrapped my `<img>` in the anchor tag but it isn't acting like a link. However the `<p>` is acting as a link. How do I get it so that I do not need the `<p>` tag to be there and the image to still work as the same link?

There is currently no cursor change on hovering over the image

```html
<div class="container">
  {% for item in page.client_images.all %} {% image item.image fill-150x150-c100 %}
  <a href="{{ item.caption }}" style="display:block;">
    <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="item" alt="{{ img.alt }}">
    <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
  </a>

  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: try to set `display: inline-block` or `display: block` to `a` tag.

Comment: @Zuber didnt work :(

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/6n10gubv/

Comment: @Paulie_D I dont know what more you need?

Comment: @Paulie_D surely extra css and html doesnt matter in this instance?

Comment: Since we can't recreate the issue from your supplied code...your output HTML & CSS **are** a necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to debug this is to check the generated HTML in your browser's developer tools. If you do this, you'll find that the order of tags is not what you expect...

This is because the template tag

```
{% image item.image fill-150x150-c100 %}
```

should be:

```
{% image item.image fill-150x150-c100 as img %}
```

If you leave out the `as img`, the tag will immediately output the `<img>` element, and since this is happening outside of the `<a>`, it will not be part of the link. Meanwhile, the `<img>` in your template code is a broken image, because it refers to the variable `img`, which isn't defined.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Knew it would be something small. I've had that `as img` elsewhere too for gallery images in a carousel. Definitely didn't totally understand why that is so necessary for  image changes.